# PHP Regex expression on all iframes without string in src

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

How can i get all iframes without comments_embed in src to use in preg_replace via regex

**Current HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMumsVillage%2Fvideos%2F881603451988373%2F&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=560" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMumsVillage%2Fvideos%2F881603451988373%2F%3Fcomment_id%3D881663971982321&amp;include_parent=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="161" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMumsVillage%2Fvideos%2F881603451988373%2F%3Fcomment_id%3D881633751985343&amp;include_parent=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="141" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMumsVillage%2Fvideos%2F881603451988373%2F&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=560" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

**Current Regular expression**

```
    <iframe[^>]+src="(?!(?:.+ )?comment_embed(?: .+)?")([^"]+)"/isg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
<iframe ((?!comment_embed).)*?<\/iframe>
```

I think the negative lookahead you want to be using is just `?!comment_embed`.  We can use this lookahead to temper a dot, as in `((?!comment_embed).)*`.  So the pattern just says to match any character, but at each step of the way look ahead and make sure we don't see `comment_embed` anywhere.  Hence, this approach should be robust to `comment_embed` appearing anywhere in the `src` URL.

As a disclaimer, in general you should not be using plain regex to parse HTML content.  Perhaps if you just want to extract these isolated top level tags, it works, but a parser would be better.

## Demo

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. How can i use it in preg_replace to wrap a div around the other divs?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind, but if you're planning on doing any DOM manipulation with a regex replace, then forget it, I'm out.  You should be using a DOM parser if you want to manipulate an HTML document.